# Angular2 mdldialogservice scroll content

Tags: angular

I am using MdlDialogService to open a help dialog from my home component:

```
openHelpDialog(){

    this.dialogService.showCustomDialog({
        component: HelpComponent,
        animate: true,
        isModal: true,
        styles: {'width': '500px', 'overflow-y':'scroll'},
        clickOutsideToClose: true

    })
}
```

And in my app component:

```
<app-home></app-home>
<dialog-outlet></dialog-outlet>
```

Now when I have a lot of help content then the modal height is simply chopped:

[image]

How can I limit the height to a certain % and then use scrolling to see the content?

Answer (score 1):

Use css max hight proprty. [css max hegight property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp)

max-height: 250px for styles property.

Answer (score 0):

I just added max-height in style like following:

```
    this.dialogService.showCustomDialog({
        component: HelpComponent,
        animate: true,
        isModal: true,
        styles: {'width': '500px', 'max-height':'500px' ,'overflow-y':'scroll'},
        clickOutsideToClose: true

    })
```